# Can I use the browser's webkitSpeechRecognition API with audio stream from chrome.tabcapture?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, speech-recognition, audio-streaming, speech-to-text

**GOAL:** Capturing audio output from a browser tab and transcribe it (*almost*) realtime, (i.e without making frequent api calls and probably using direct audio streams rather than, capturing stream + converting to .wav/.mp3 )

**Current SOLUTION:** I am developing a chrome extension where I want to start capturing audio stream from any tab using the *chrome.tabcapture* API --> https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture
and then transcribe it locally in-browser, via the *web speech api*  -->
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API

any efficient way of doing this is also welcomed !

Comment: can you share code of current solution